# Using PassManager in llvm 6

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm trying to update a llvm 3.6 code to llvm 6.0 and I can't find out how to use PassManager in this version.

I used the following code in 3.6 :

```
llvm::PassManager pm;
pm.add(new MyPass);
pm.run();
```

This code is refused by the compiler : error: declaration of variable 'pm' with deduced type 'llvm::PassManager' requires an initializer
    llvm::PassManager pm;

I don't get what initializer is required, I see in LLVM's sources that PassManager have a default constructor.

What i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `llvm::legacy::PassManager` instead of just `llvm::PassManager`. To use it, you need to include LegacyPassManager.h. (`#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"`)

`llvm::PassManager` [is actually a class template](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PassManager.html).

Comment: There seem to be no legacy namespace in llvm 6.0 : error: no member named 'legacy' in namespace 'llvm'
    llvm::legacy::PassManager pm;
But llvm::PassManager still is a templated class. What should I use as template parameter ? 
It seems to need a IRUnitT required parameter but nothing is explained about that. Thank you

Comment: @dvr33 Did you `#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"` ?